# Can sbt-native-packager generate multiple start scripts for one project?

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

I'm currently using [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) to generate a start script for my scala application.  I'm using `packageArchetype.java_application`.  I create the script in sbt:

```
sbt clean myproject/stage
```

and then "install" the application by copying the created `lib` and `bin` directories to the installation directory.  I'm not distributing it to anyone, so I'm not creating an executable jar or tarball or anything like that.  I'm just compiling my classes, and putting my jar and all the library dependency jars in one place so the start script can execute.

Now I want to add a second main class to my application, so I want a second start script to appear in `target/universal/stage/bin` when I run `sbt stage`.  I expect it will be the same script but with a different name and `app_mainclass` set to the different class.   How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The sbt-native-packager generated script allows you to pass in a `-main` argument to specify the main class you want to run.  Here's what I do for a project named `foo`:

Create a `run.sh` script with whatever common options you want that calls the sbt-native-packager generated script:

```
#!/bin/bash

./target/universal/stage/bin/foo -main "$@"
```

Then I create a separate script for each main class I want to run.  For example `first.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

./run.sh com.example.FirstApp -- "$@"
```

and `second.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC"

./run.sh com.example.SecondApp -- "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

Having multiple main classes is... supported now (Q4 2016, native package 1.2.0)

See "[SBT Native Packager 1.2.0](https://medium.com/@muuki88/sbt-native-packager-1-2-0-a93e305888c5#.dazrhbfvm)" by **[Muki Seiler](https://twitter.com/muuki88)**

> ### Single Project — Multiple Apps
>
> A major pain point for beginners is the start script creation. The bash and bat start scripts are only generated when there is a either
>
> - Exactly one main class
> - Explicitly set main class with

```
     mainClass in Compile := Some(“com.example.MainClass”)
```

> For 1.2.x we will extends the implementation and support multiple main classes by default.
>
> **Native packager will generate a start script for each main class found on the classpath**.
>   **SBT provides them via the `discoveredMainClasses` in `Compile` task**.
>   If there is only one main class, SBT will assign it to the `mainClass` in Compile setting. This leads to three cases:
>
> - **Exactly one main class**.
>     In this case native-packager will behave like previous versions and just generate a single start script, using the `executableScriptName` setting for the script name.
> - **Multiple main classes and mainClass in `Compile := None`**.
>     This is the default behaviour defined by SBT. In this case native-packager will generate the same start script for each main class.
> - **Multiple main classes and mainClass in `Compile := Some(…)`**.
>     The user has set a specific main class, which will lead to a main start script being generated using the `executableScriptName` setting. For all other main classes native-packager generates forwarder scripts.

Comment: Can you prevent forwarder scripts from being generated when there are multiple main classes and `mainClass in Compile := Some(…)`?

Comment: @AndrewBate That I don't know: could you ask that as an independent question, for other to have a look at it?

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning on which version this started to be supported (1.2.0) as I was using an older one and this wouldn't work

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple main classes not supported now. As a workaround you could use single main class and check command line args. 
Starting your app:

```
myApp prog1
```

In your main class:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  if(args[0] == "prog1")
    Programm1.start()
  else 
    Programm2.start()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestion.  I just added a line to my "install" script that runs the generated start script through `sed` to make a copy in which the `app_mainclass` line is modified.

Comment: Any plans to support this in the near future?

Comment: Sbt native packager now supports `-main` parameter in bash script.
`app_name -main some.other.Main`.

Comment: @kardapoltsev how? Any documentation link?

Comment: Just pass -main parameter to your start script. Few docs could be found at
http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/